# NodeJS Cluster Module

Tags: node.js, worker

I am testing the cluster module for NodeJS. I am trying to achieve the following:

- Start the HTTP server with two cluster workers.
- Once the master and workers are started, master sends a "check"
  message to the workers every 5 seconds
- If the worker respond back then the counter is set to 0
- If there is no message before the next "check" message then the
  counter is incremented.
- I check if the worker did not respond for 20 consequent seconds then
  I kill the worker and let the master start a new worker.

The Problem that I am facing is:

- When I kill the worker, the next worker goes into a loop of restart,kill,restart,kill etc which means at any point of time only one worker is active and the other worker is unresponsive due to which it goes into a loop.

My code is:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var http = require('http');
var numCPUs = 2;
var workerStatus = new Object();

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Fork workers.
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork(); 
    }

    cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
        cluster.fork();
        console.log('worker %d died (%s). restarting...', worker.process.pid, signal || code);      
    });


  // Go through all workers
    function eachWorker(callback) {
      for (var id in cluster.workers) {     
        callback(cluster.workers[id],id);
      }
    }
    setInterval(function (){
        eachWorker(function(worker,id) {    
            if (workerStatus[id] == undefined)  workerStatus[id]=-1;
            if (workerStatus[id] < 4){
                workerStatus[id]++;
                console.log("Message Sent : " + id);
                worker.send('check');
            }else{
                delete workerStatus[id]
                console.log("Some Problem with " + id);
                worker.disconnect();
                worker.kill();
            }
        });
    },5000);

    eachWorker(function(worker,id){
        var w_id =id;
        worker.on('message', function(msg){
            workerStatus[w_id]=0;
            console.log("Message Received : " + w_id);
        });
    });

} else {
    process.on('message', function(msg) {
        process.send(msg);
    });

  // Workers can share any TCP connection
  // In this case its a HTTP server
  http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    while (1) {}
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("hello world--" + cluster.worker.id);
    //cluster.worker.kill();
  }).listen(8080);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.

When I kill the worker and start a new worker, I do not add a listener for the newly created worked. Due to which the message is never received for the newly created worker.

Just by adding the following code, the issue was fixed.

```
cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
    var w = cluster.fork();
    console.log('worker %d died (%s). restarting...', worker.process.pid, signal || code);
    w.on('message', function(msg){
        workerStatus[w.id]=0;
        console.log("Message Received : " + w.id);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have simple support module that separates the worker script (and simply loads different scripts + handles communication), that could help: [runworker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/runworker)